# heatmap for large dataframe after grouping

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I have a huge data frame that looks something like what i've attached below. I would like to group-by the column 'sscinames' as it has similar entries like 'Acidobacteria bacterium'    (get the sum of it for each sample) and then plot a heatmap. Would like the heat map to only show the top 20 'sscinames' based on the sample count. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sscinames   S3_Day90_P3 S3_Day60_P3 S3_Day0_P1  S3_Day60_P1 S3_Day90_P1
    Thermoplasmata archaeon 4   0   41  1   5
    Planctomycetes bacterium    5   3   0   1   40
    Acidobacteria bacterium 6   15  0   8   13
    Trebonia kvetii 0   0   16  1   7
    Nonomuraea sp. RK-328   24  4   4   1   2
    Nitrospirae bacterium   3   1   4   1   2
    Acidobacteria bacterium 11  11  0   9   27
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a few steps, but it is a perfect task for pandas and seaborn. I commented the example below to give you an idea of what is happening there.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# This is just to create a dataframe from your table, replace with importing yours
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Thermoplasmata archaeon",  4,  0, 41, 1,  5],
                    ["Planctomycetes bacterium", 5,  3,  0, 1, 40],
                    ["Acidobacteria bacterium",  6, 15,  0, 8, 13],
                    ["Trebonia kvetii",          0,  0, 16, 1,  7],
                    ["Nonomuraea sp. RK-328",   24,  4,  4, 1,  2],
                    ["Nitrospirae bacterium",    3,  1,  4, 1,  2],
                    ["Acidobacteria bacterium", 11, 11,  0, 9, 27]])
df1.columns = ["sscinames", "S3_Day90_P3", "S3_Day60_P3",  "S3_Day0_P1", "S3_Day60_P1", "S3_Day90_P1"]

# Create column with total sample count
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:,1:].T.sum()) # This sums (along rows, hence the .T) all samples for each row
df2.columns = ["Total Samples"]
# ...and merge with your data frame to add the new column (axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# Now, turn the first column into a pandas index (then seaborn uses it immediately to label the axes)
df = df.set_index(['sscinames'])

# You can now sort your dataframe by the new column and proceed with the top entries
df = df.sort_values(by="Total Samples", ascending=False)
df_slice2plot = df.iloc[:5, :] # This takes the top five rows and all the columns, change as needed

# Now, on to plotting
sns.heatmap(df_slice2plot.iloc[:, 1:]) # Plot numeric columns (first column, with index 0, are the labels)
```

This is the result I get:

[A heatmap of the example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dovgs.png)

Answer (score 3):

First aggregate sum and then for top `N` value by `sum` per aggregate rows use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

Last for heatmap use [`seaborn.heatmap`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

N = 3
df1 = df.groupby('sscinames').sum()

out = df1.reindex(df1.sum(axis=1).nlargest(N).index)
print (out)
                          S3_Day90_P3  S3_Day60_P3  S3_Day0_P1  S3_Day60_P1  \
sscinames                                                                     
Acidobacteria bacterium            17           26           0           17   
Thermoplasmata archaeon             4            0          41            1   
Planctomycetes bacterium            5            3           0            1   

                          S3_Day90_P1  
sscinames                              
Acidobacteria bacterium            40  
Thermoplasmata archaeon             5  
Planctomycetes bacterium           40  


sns.heatmap(out, annot=True)
```

[image]

Comment: hi @jezrael thank you for the response. I have over 30 samples, but looks like only some of it are being displayed at x-axis. Is there away to alter the heatmap to display all the names and remove all the numbers that  within the heatmap as it looks very messy.

Comment: @sumitrasivaprakasam - Can you try `sns.heatmap(out)` ?

Comment: This removed the numbers within the heatmap but the cant seem to display all the samples names.

Comment: got it with sns.heatmap(out,xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True). I can see all the labels now